# How to get function of "GaussianProcess" prediction?

Tags: fitting, machine-learning

I am a new user of Wolfram Mathematica. I need your help.

Let's say I have three variables: x, y, z. I want to calculate the "z" depending on x, and y. In other words, I want to find a function for z like `z=f(x,y)`.

I have this data

```
y = {140, 360, 500, 740, 800};

x = {4, 10, 35, 70, 90};

z = {{97.438, 103.891, 110.344, 118.7545, 124.13475},
    {110.344, 116.797, 123.25, 127.165, 129.515},
    {118.7545, 122.95975, 127.165, 131.08, 131.865},
    {121.444625, 124.8923125, 128.34, 131.4725, 132.2575},
    {124.13475, 126.824875, 129.515, 131.865, 132.65}
    };
```

I have found this thread
[enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66086/developing-a-function-of-two-variables-from-given-data)

based on which I have

1. Created the plots of the data `ListPlot3D[vals, Mesh -> All]`

[image]
 2. Created the predict and prediction is by "LinearRegression"

```
trainingSet = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Rule[{s[[i]], t[[j]]}, data[[i, j]]], {i, Length@s}, {j, 
     Length@t}], 1];
pf = Predict[trainingSet, Method -> "LinearRegression"];
Show[Plot3D[pf[{x, y}], {x, Min@s, Max@s}, {y, Min@t, Max@t}], 
 ListPointPlot3D[vals, PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> Large}]]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

LinearRegression results.

[image]

it doesn't represent all the points that I need.

3. By "`PredictorInformation[pf, "Function"]`"
   I get the function of my data. The function is = "109.712 + 0.115408 #1 + 0.0168067 #2 &"

However, the prediction is linear which doesn't fully give me what I want to see.
There is another prediction method which is "GaussianProcess" and it gives me what I want it to see.

[image]

but when I try to get the function of it by `"PredictorInformation[pf, "Function"]"`

there is an error "`PredictorInformation::elmntavs: "Function" is not an available property. Did you mean "FunctionMemory" instead?`"

So my question is: Is there a way of getting the function of GaussianProcess prediction?

Or if there is not a way for that. How can I get a function of z = f(x,y)
that would represent my data properly?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the full functional expression of a fitted Gaussian process would be a pretty big and ugly beast that basically involves all data points that were used to make the fit as well as a matrix inversion. A Gaussian process is more like an interpolation function than a linear model in that sense. That's probably the reason they don't give you the function explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there another way to get a function of z = f(x,y) that would represent my data properly?

Comment: If you just want an analytical formula, you should probably use `Fit` or `NonlinearModelFit` (a 2nd degree model will probably do). Predict is a machine learning method that is geared towards prediction of unseen values and not so much towards fitting a model you can easily interpret.

Comment: Is there a guide I can use or some examples of this kind of data with z = f(x,y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can fit a 2D polynomial to your data:

```
y = {140, 360, 500, 740, 800};

x = {4, 10, 35, 70, 90};

z = {{97.438, 103.891, 110.344, 118.7545, 124.13475}, {110.344, 
    116.797, 123.25, 127.165, 129.515}, {118.7545, 122.95975, 127.165,
     131.08, 131.865}, {121.444625, 124.8923125, 128.34, 131.4725, 
    132.2575}, {124.13475, 126.824875, 129.515, 131.865, 132.65}};
fitdata = Catenate @ Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}, {j, 1, Length[y]}];
fit = Fit[fitdata, {1, x1, x2, x1 x2, x1^2, x2^2}, {x1, x2}]
Show[
 Plot3D[fit, {x1, Min[x], Max[x]}, {x2, Min[y], Max[y]}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ListPlot3D[fitdata]
]
```

> > Out[21]= 94.7557 + 0.645641 x1 - 0.00383606 x1^2 + 0.0364044 x2 - 
> >      0.000257039 x1 x2 - 2.21253*10^-6 x2^2

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much it worked for me. I changed the fit data equation to (1, x1, x2, x1^2, x1 x2, x2^2, x1^3, x1^2 x2, x1 x2^2, x2^3) and got good results.
Also as you suggested I tried to use "NonlinearModelFit" which gave me the "BestFitParameters" but they don't seem to be the best fit parameters.

Really thank you so much I appreciate your help. If didn't publish this example I would struggle all day long.

Comment: With `NonlinearModelFit`, you pretty much always need to specify good initial guesses for your parameters. That's just the nature of fitting nonlinear models: there's no algorithm that guarantees a good result. Linear fits (i.e., linear in the basis functions) are much easier in that respect.

Comment: I have also found the "FindFormula". Right now don't get how it works but I am trying to find out.

Comment: `FindFormula` does not work for 2D data AFAIK.